# Show that 2020 divides $p\left( n \right)$ for every integer $n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers

Consider:
$$p\left( n \right)=800n+400{{n}^{2}}+400{{n}^{4}}+200{{n}^{5}}+100{{n}^{10}}+100{{n}^{20}}+8{{n}^{101}}+4{{n}^{202}}+4{{n}^{404}}+2{{n}^{505}}+{{n}^{1010}}+{{n}^{2020}}$$
**Show that: $2020$ divides $p\left( n \right)$ for every positive integer $n$?**

Work: the statement is indeed true for $n=1,2..100$ , of course using a computer!!

Comment: Prove it for each power of a prime dividing $2020$.  For $2^2=4$, note that all the terms except the last three are divisible by $4$.  If $n$ is even the last three are all divisible by $4$.  If $n$ is odd, $2n^{505} \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ and the last two are equivalent to $1 \pmod 4$, so the sum is divisible by $4$.  Over to you for the other two.

Comment: I suggest considering the prime factors of $2020$, but there may be a simpler way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce mod $101$ and by an application of Fermat's little theorem of the form $n^{100} \equiv 1\pmod {101}$ and the symmetric nature of the polynomial, the terms cancel like so: $-8n -4n^{2}-4n^{4}-2n^{5}-n^{10}-n^{20}+8n+4n^{2}+4n^{4}+2n^{5}+n^{10}+n^{20} \equiv 0 \pmod {101}$ so that $101 | p(n)$.

Reduce $\pmod {20}$ to see that we need to show that $20| 
8{{n}^{101}}+4{{n}^{202}}+4{{n}^{404}}+2{{n}^{505}}+{{n}^{1010}}+{{n}^{2020}}$.

By Ross's hint, the right side is easily seen to be divisible by $4$.

All that is left is to show $5 | 8{{n}^{101}}+4{{n}^{202}}+4{{n}^{404}}+2{{n}^{505}}+{{n}^{1010}}+{{n}^{2020}}$

By another application of Fermat's little theorem, $n^4 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$, the right side becomes $8n +4n^{2}+4+2n+n^{2}+1 \equiv 10n +5n^{2}+5 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$.

Altogether, this means that $2020 | p(n)$ for all $n$.